# Where is bufWriter documented in Golang?

Tags: go

I see `bufWriter` used here. But I am not sure where it is defined and documented. Could anybody show me where it is? Thanks.

https://github.com/google/codesearch/blob/master/index/write.go#L44

Comment: https://github.com/google/codesearch/blob/master/index/write.go#L453

Comment: It's not _documented_ anywhere. It's an unexported type, which means it's defined in the same package that's referencing it (as comments have already pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the definition of `bufWriter` on lines 453 to 577 of the file you posted: https://github.com/google/codesearch/blob/master/index/write.go#L452-L577

It only has a little bit of documentation in the comments, but you can also read through the code.

By the way, in Go, structs declared with `lowerCamelCase` names are private to the package they are declared in. `UpperCamelCase` named structs are public. Thus, the declaration of `bufWriter` must be inside the `index` package somewhere since it's private.